# Action to open attachments panel

Tags: java, itext

Is there an action which opens the attachments panel? Not right away, but when the user presses some text?

I know the `writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeUseAttachments)` but I don't want it to open right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a JavaScript action:

```
Chunk c = new Chunk("Show / Hide attachment panel");
c.setAction(PdfAction.javaScript("app.execMenuItem('ShowHideFileAttachment');", writer));
document.add(new Paragraph(c));
```

Note that this won't work on all viewers (app = Adobe Reader) and it won't work if people disable Javascript.

Comment: hi, it seems that this solution is not working on mobile phones. I used the adobe reader application. Is there any support for actions / references / launch or javascripts on mobile phones using acrobat reader ?

Comment: In the first version of Adobe Reader I installed on my mobile phone, I was only able to read PDFs as 'flat' documents. All interactivity such as links, annotations, fields,... didn't work. With every new update, new functionality was added, but Reader for mobile devices is still very different from Reader for the desktop. I expect that there will always be difference due to the different nature of the devices. E.g.: triggering a menu item execution isn't likely to work ever if the menu on the mobile app is totally different. In short: don't expect this to work unless Adobe start supporting it.